# No longer receiving Windows 10 insider previews on desktop

Tags: windows-10, windows-10-preview

I have my laptop formatted with dual boot. The primary partition with Windows 10, and the secondary partition also with windows 10, but set to receive Windows insider preview updates. However, since the secondary partition reached build version 10586.164 it has not updated any further. What could be wrong? In the advanced updates the correct account subscribed to the insider program is listed, and fast ring selected. The Windows Insider app providing announcements and so on works fine also.

Comment: Have you tried to leave the Insider Preview?

Comment: Yes it was one of the things I tried  - I opted out on that machine, rebooted as per the instructions, and then opted back in and rebooted again. Then I left the machine on some time, and periodically tried checking for updates - but nothing....

Comment: So both installations are on the current stable build?

Comment: That's correct.

Comment: is it due to the 30 day rule?

Comment: @highBandWidth Could you perhaps expand? What is the 30 day rule?

Comment: Windows 10 won't install a new build within 30 days of 7/8 upgrade to Windows 10. This is so the last system to recover is Windows 7/8 in case the user changes their mind. I don't think that it's documented though.

Comment: @highBandWidth Thanks for the explanation. I can confirm I am well past that window, so that won't be it.